# React native expo android crashes when navigate to another screen from a component

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

- I am using React Navigation version 6.
- I have 3 screens.
- Screens are: Home, MovieDetail , PlayScreen , ***SimilarMovieScreen (crashed on this screen)*** .

1. Home screen has react-native-snap-carousel, upon pressing on the carousel it redirects to MovieDetail screen ,
2. MovieDetail screen has a "watch now" button, upon pressing on it, it redirects to playscreen.
3. PlayScreen has another carousel component , upon clicking it should take to another screen named SimilarMovieScreen.

***CarouselComponent code***

```
const SimilarSliderImage = ({data }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>{
            navigation.navigate("SimilarMovieScreen") // crashed onPressing this carousel
          }}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data.poster_path || [],
          }}
          style={styles.imgStyle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

***Stacknavigator code***

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true ,headerTintColor: colorScheme ==="dark" ? "white" : "black"}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MovieDetail" component={MovieDetail} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PlayScreen" component={PlayScreen} />     
      <Stack.Screen name="SimilarMovieScreen" component={SimilarMovieScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

When i press on playscreen carousel it just crashes on my android phone. I got no crash reports or anything. So, how do i fix this React Navigation v6 error.

Comment: Can you comment the Image component and check if (uri: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data.poster_path || []) is the reason for the error or not

Comment: @Thanhal i have tried commenting it and it is still crashing. In fact image is loading properly in carousel no issue in that i guess.

Comment: Oh.. Did you get any error logs?

Comment: no error logs, the app just crashed.

Comment: Ya could you get crash logs using adb or something? also can you share the full code here

Comment: i have tried adb logcat and expo sentry but did not work, will share related code

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the exact same problem right now and I found that adding `cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid` to `screenOptions` worked, but I still don't understand why...